# Calling member function through a pointer from Python with pybind11

Tags: segmentation-fault, pybind11

I am creating a Python module (`module.so`) following [pybind11's tutorial on trampolines](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html):

```cpp
// module.cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

class IReader
{
  public:
  virtual std::vector<int> read(const std::string &path) = 0;
};

class PyIReader : public IReader
{
  using IReader::IReader;
  std::vector<int> read(const std::string &path) override
  {
    PYBIND11_OVERRIDE_PURE(std::vector<int>, IReader, read, path);
  }
};

class C
{
  public:
  C(IReader *reader) : reader_(reader) {}
  std::vector<int> workOn(const std::string &path) { return reader_->read(path); }

  private:
  IReader *reader_;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(module, m)
{
  py::class_<IReader, PyIReader>(m, "IReader").def(py::init<>()).def("read", &IReader::read);
  // I need call_guard to avoid deadlocking in my real code;
  // but removing it doesn't help
  py::class_<C>(m, "C").def(py::init<IReader *>()).def("work_on", &C::workOn, py::call_guard<py::gil_scoped_release>());
}
```

and

```py
# main.py
import pickle
from typing import *
from module import IReader, C


class PklReader(IReader):
    def read(self, path: str) -> List[int]:
        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            return pickle.load(f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = C(PklReader())
    print(c.work_on("a.pkl"))    # a = [1, 2, 3]
```

The Python snippet always gives a segmentation fault. I doubt that GIL is the culprit as an interpreter is embedded to run the Python code, but I am not sure what goes wrong.

(I've read [passing pointer to C++ from python using pybind11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57990269/688080) but it seems another question for me as the pointer there is `double *` so no class members)

Also my `CMakelists.txt` if it's helpful:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(CLASS_POINTER)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_compile_options(-O3 -fopenmp -fPIC)
add_link_options(-fopenmp)
find_package(Python 3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development NumPy)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)

pybind11_add_module(module module.cpp)
set_target_properties(module PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
target_include_directories(module PRIVATE ${pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_directories(module PRIVATE ${Python_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(module PRIVATE ${pybind11_LIBRARIES} ${Python_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiving raw pointers usually<sup>*</sup> means you don't assume ownership of the object. When you receive `IReader*` in the constructor of `C`, pybind11 assumes you will still hold the temporary `PklReader()` object and keep it alive outside. But you don't, so it gets freed and you get a segfault.

I think

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pr = PklReader()
    c = C(pkr)
    print(c.work_on("a.pkl"))    # a = [1, 2, 3]
```

should work, given everything else is correct.

You can also receive and store a `shared_ptr` in `C` to receive ownership of the reader.

<sup>*</sup> C++ Core Guidelines: [Never transfer ownership by a raw pointer or reference.](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#i11-never-transfer-ownership-by-a-raw-pointer-t-or-reference-t)

Comment: Yes it works, thanks.