# Does pybind11 create a copy when passing bytes/string from python to C++?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, zero-copy

I'm trying to use pybind11 to bind heavy computing in C++ with python as front end (unfortunately). I need to pass string/bytes around from python to C++ and back. After reading through the [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/strings.html#passing-bytes-to-c), I thought that **"without conversion"** meaning that the memory address of C++ and python should be the same when passing around, they are looking at the same data. Here is the dummy code:

In c++:

```cpp
void string_fn(std::string& x) {
    std::cout << "c++ value is:  " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c++ address is: " << &x << std::endl;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(module_name, module_handle) {
  module_handle.def("string_fn", &string_fn, py::return_value_policy::reference);
}
```

Pass data from python:

```py
a = "test_string" # same output with a = b"test_string"
print("python address: ", hex(id(a)))

# call c++ function
string_fn(a)
```

Outputs are:

```
python address:  0x7f268c65f240
c++ value is:  test_string
c++ address is: 0x7ffff24c1830
```

As we can see, the value is the same but the address is different.
I'm a total noob and my questions are:

1. Am I printing the right thing? Or pybind11 just create a copy of python string?
2. If I'm doing it wrong, how should I achieve it with zero copy?

Comment: I do not understand how the title is related to the question

Comment: I guess "without conversion" mentioned in "Passing bytes to C++" means that python will not convert `py::bytes` to `py::str`. About pythonic `id` being the same as transformed argument to c++ function - I don't see anywhere any mentions about it.

Comment: "string/bytes" String **or** bytes? These are totally different things.

Comment: Hi guys,

I'm sorry for the confusion. I'm just trying to pass data from python to c++ without it making a copy.  Following the docs, I thought that "without conversion" meant that c++ and python should point to the same data, with no need to convert to c++ type. Is there anywhere in the doc I should look into to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990269/passing-pointer-to-c-from-python-using-pybind11

Comment: I'd say there's definitely a copy involved to be able to get a `std::string&` since a) without that you would be able to modify the immutable Python string and b) AFAIK `std::string` owns its data, and there's no (normal) way to make a non-owning one. | What is the bigger problem you're trying to solve? What sort of data is it, what do you want to do with it exactly? | For example OpenCV uses numpy arrays on Python side to facilitate passing large mutable arrays back and forth efficiently. Pybind11 has support for those.